# React + Django Azure application security

Tags: reactjs, django, azure, deployment, authorization

My goal is to deploy to the Azure, cloud application that conists of React frontend and Django backend.
I would like my frontend to be publicly accessible, but available only behind some authentication mechanism (I found password protection in Static Web Apps in Azure), maybe Microsoft SSO.
My Django API should not be accessible publicy (I want my frontend to the be only source of REST queries).

I have created React as Static Web App and Django as Web App, but I did not manage to find a way to exclusively connect them together. I have tried backend to be secured with Microsoft SSO, but as I assume, it requires additional changes in fronted (with authentication).

My question is: what is the proper solution to deploy such application (maybe it should be just deployed as one virtual machine)?
Should I use any other resource types?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can proper configure CORS and allow only your Static Web App as a valid origin to call your API.

using Azure CLI:

```
az webapp cors add --resource-group <group-name> --name <app-name> --allowed-origins 'https://*.contoso.com'
```

More info:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-rest-api#app-service-cors-vs-your-cors

You can also host your API behind Azure API Management and require a subscription key:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-subscriptions#manage-subscription-keys